How to remove word after ")." line by line?
I have a text and want to remove any word after ).
A).     Buyers of potato
B).     Buyers of egg
C).     Buyers of gasolin
W). The price meat

The desired output would be:
->A).   
->B).   
->C).   
->W). 

I've tried using \).* which doesn't look like a good idea to start with.

Why is it not a good idea? Do you mean you want to insert -> at the start of each line after removing all after ).? Note you only match ) with your regex, not )., which can be done with \)\..*

When using Notepad++ you can do the following:
Search for: (^\w+\)\.).*
Replace by: ->\1
This captures the desired beginning of the line in the first capture group and outputs it prepended with ->.
